# What map choice (e.g. Google, Bing, etc) for my SaaS product?

Tags: google-maps, maps, bing-maps

Part of what I want to offer subscribers to my application is a map showing the location of their customer, with the option to get directions (the idea is that they can just easily get the directions from one place instead of copying/pasting and going to Google Maps or Mapquest or whichever).  As I understand it, however, Google Maps will require me to pay to use their API as my application is only visible to paid subscribers.  I've contacted their Sales department to try and see just how much, but honestly any amount is too much since my startup is bootstrapped and I have little or no funds for anything.

This has got me looking at alternatives since I don't intend to pay to use a mapping API.  Of the available maps, which one would you say is the most reliable as far as locations and directions?  I'm considering Bing maps (formerly Live Maps) since it looks like I'm going to be using ASP.NET MVC as my platform of choice (Hey, I have a BizSpark membership for another two years - I might as well use it!) but I haven't checked their TOS to see if they have a similar proviso to Google Maps in that you need a special license if the map is only visible to paying customers.

**EDIT:** I guess what I'm asking is if there is any mapping service that *won't* charge an arm and a leg to use their mapping service on a paid, password-protected site?  I was hoping to make the map integration a major feature of my product, but we're a startup so there's no money for expensive licenses for something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it on a password protected page with Google Maps API would require a Premier Licence. Each such licence is negotiable, but prices generally start at $10000 p.a.

One possibility to consider is throwing the directions request at maps.google.com in a new browser window or popup. Pass the start and end addresses in the &saddr and &daddr parameters. Or making your own public facing map page and opening that in a popup.

Comment: Good lord.  I guess that's my solution then, since there's no way I have that sort of money for what will be a roughly $60/month subscription app.  I always wondered why nobody did that before, I guess now I have my answer!

Answer (score 6):

You could use OpenLayers, Mapnik and [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org) to roll your own maps and direction-finding functionality, or you could talk to [Cloudmade](http://www.cloudmade.com) to help do this for you. Because the underlying map data is free, I think Cloudmade are much cheaper than Google, Yahoo and Bing for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, man.  I just developed my own SaaS app and today came across the pricing from Google and Bing - after building in an asp.net framework and using Bing to get map (time/distance) data.  Not even using any visual display/scrolling/zooming functionality.

It would be really nice if MSFT, Google, et al would provide SME pricing along with "enterprise" pricing - we are 2 different kinds of businesses.  And I'm bootstrapped as well.  Hope I am not scr3wed...

Answer (score 1):

SpatialKey http://www.spatialkey.com provides a good solution for SaaS mapping and doesn't tie you into a single mapping provider. Their default is Mapquest but they provide Openstreet maps as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very happy with Bing. My company has an enterprise license and it isn't cheap. BUT, they've just announced new licensing (http://www.microsoft.com/maps/resources/news.aspx).

"Free licensing for small Web sites. It’s now even easier to get started with Bing Maps—use is now free for public-facing, non-password protected Web sites with up to 125,000 user sessions per year.*"

So it may be within your reach :)

Comment: Ah so it's the same then... my site isn't "public facing" since the maps require you have a paid subscription in order to view.